# best practice of tensorflow dynamic loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to implement a two-round-for loop.

And find it is difficult to do by using `tf.while_loop`

What is the best way to implement a two-round-for loop by tensorflow?

I hope it could be like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5])
b = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5])

sess = tf.Session()

for i in tf.range(tf.constant(0),tf.shape(a)[0]):
    for j in tf.range(tf.constant(0),tf.shape(b)[0]):
        print(sess.run([i,j]))
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify the behavior that you want, but my guess is that the code you pasted will not do what you expect. Here are some options you have:

- Use `tf.while_loop`. This will construct a graph with while loops. When you run such a graph, it will run efficiently in C++ runtime using CPU or GPU.
- Use regular python loops (`for i in range(10):`) and do multiple calls to `session.run()`. This way whatever operations you need to do between calls to `session.run()` will happen in python and can be slow. For example, the output tensors you pass to `session.run()` are copied to CPU memory (if main computation is done on GPU). This approach is generally discouraged.
- Use the recently released [eager execution](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/README.md) - there are links for more docs in the "Documentation" section. Eager execution allows you do use arbitrary python code for control flow but all operations are still done efficiently on CPU/GPU.